# How to prove that this set of reals has an upper bound?

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

Let $r$ be a strictly positive real number. How to prove that ${\{x \in \mathbb R_{\ge0}:x^2<r}\}$ has an upper bound?

Answer (score 2):

For instance $\max(1,r)$  is an upper bound.

Comment: And how would I prove that?

Comment: Because, if $ r\ge 1$, $r\le r^2$, so $x^2<r^2$, which implies $x<r$ for a non-negative $x$. And if $r\le1$,  $x^2<r\le1$ implies $x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)=x^2$ is a strictly increasing function on $(0,\infty)$, and $x^2\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.  So, for any $r$, you can make $x$ "big enough" that $x^2$ exceeds $r$; and, once that happens, any $y>x$ also satisfies $y^2>r$.  Hence the set is bounded above by such an $x$.